# ¿Cómo eliminar una fila que tiene dos Ids diferentes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Mi programa se trata de una tabla que agrega filas, mi problema es que cuando trato de borrar una fila que no tiene dos Ids diferentes se borran los dos fila, un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el imagen muestra 3 filas con sus datos y la columna Acomodación tiene su propio Id y también la columna Categoría tiene su propio Id la primera fila se descarta correctamente ok, mi problema esta en la fila 2 y 3 si vemos la fila 2 y 3  hay 2 Acomodaciones iguales "Hab Doble", pero en la Categoría son diferentes, y cuando hago click en uno de los botones de la fila 2 y 3 se descartan los dos y eso no es la idea. debería descartarse uno solo.

Éste es mi código:

```
function addPerson(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var repetido = "NO";
    var ideA = $('#cboAcomodacion').val();
    var ideC = $('#cboCategoria').val();
    var valoresA = $('#cboAcomodacion option:selected').text();
    var vprecio = $('#txtPrecioTa').val();
    var valoresC = $('#cboCategoria option:selected').text();
    $("#TablaHotTarifas tbody tr").each(function (index) {
        $(this).children("td").each(function (index2) {
            if ($(this).text() == ideA && $(this).text() == ideC) { repetido = "SI"; }
        })
    })
    var datoA = $('#cboAcomodación').val();
    var datoC = $('#cboCategoria').val();
    if (repetido == "NO"  && datoA != 0 && vprecio != "" && datoC != 0) {
        var ideA = $('#cboAcomodacion').val();
        var ideC = $('#cboCategoria').val();
        var valoresA = $('#cboAcomodacion option:selected').text();
        var vprecio = $('#txtPrecioTa').val();
        var valoresC = $('#cboCategoria option:selected').text();
        alert("id Acomodacion = " + ideA  " + id categoria = " + ideC  )
        const row = createRow({
            id: ideA,
            idC: ideC,
            valorA: valoresA,
            precio: vprecio,
            valorC: valoresC,                                 
            descartar: "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-danger boton' id='" + ideA + "' id '" + ideC + "'  onclick='remove(" + ideA + ", " + ideC + " )'>Descartar</button> ",
        });

        $('#TablaHotTarifas tbody').append(row)
        $('#cboAcomodacion').val(0);
        $("#txtPrecioTa").val("");
        $("#cboCategoria").val(0);
    } else {
        alert("Datos incorrectos, verifique los campos que esten llenados");
    }
}
function createRow(data) {
    return (
    `<tr id=${data.id} >` +
        `<td style="display:none" >${data.id}, ${data.idC}</td>` +        
        `<td>${data.valorA}</td>` +
        `<td>${data.precio}</td>` +        
        `<td>${data.valorC}</td>` +
        `<td>${data.descartar}</td>` +
    `</tr>`
    );
}
function remove(ideA, ideC) {
    alert("id A = " + ideA + " ideC = " + ideC)
    $("#TablaHotTarifas > tbody > tr#" + ideA +","+ ideC).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien pues una opción seria, si solo quieres borrar la fila de la vista y no de la base de datos, seria asignarle un identificador a cada fila de la tabla html, este "id", el cual estaria en el botón, no tiene nada que ver con un identificador en la base de datos, solo es para diferenciar la fila en la tabla html.

Otra opción, si no quieres agregarle un identificador a cada fila, simplemente al pulsar sobre el botón obtener su contenedor es decir el elemento "tr" y borrarlo.

Ahora bien, si lo quieres borrar de la base de datos, deberías colocar tantos datos como sean necesarios para identificar esa información y no solo el "id".